# Magento emails not sending - core_email_queue table is empty in database

Tags: php, email, magento, templates, cron

No emails are being sent from magento. Cron is set up properly and I've just noticed that now the core_email_queue table is empty in the database, although we have had new orders. I've tried various things with template.php to get the emails to work but have always reverted my changes so dont think anything is wrong there?

Template.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Magento
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@magento.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
 * versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
 * needs please refer to http://www.magento.com for more information.
 *
 * @category    Mage
 * @package     Mage_Core
 * @copyright  Copyright (c) 2006-2015 X.commerce, Inc. (http://www.magento.com)
 * @license    http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php  Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 */

/**
 * Template model
 *
 * Example:
 *
 * // Loading of template
 * $emailTemplate  = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')
 *    ->load(Mage::getStoreConfig('path_to_email_template_id_config'));
 * $variables = array(
 *    'someObject' => Mage::getSingleton('some_model')
 *    'someString' => 'Some string value'
 * );
 * $emailTemplate->send('some@domain.com', 'Name Of User', $variables);
 *
 * @method Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Email_Template _getResource()
 * @method Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Email_Template getResource()
 * @method string getTemplateCode()
 * @method Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template setTemplateCode(string $value)
 * @method string getTemplateText()
 * @method Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template setTemplateText(string $value)
 * @method string getTemplateStyles()
 * @method Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template setTemplateStyles(string $value)
 * @method int getTemplateType()
 * @method Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template setTemplateType(int $value)
 * @method string getTemplateSubject()
 * @method Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template setTemplateSubject(string $value)
 * @method string getTemplateSenderName()
 * @method Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template setTemplateSenderName(string $value)
 * @method string getTemplateSenderEmail()
 * @method Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template setTemplateSenderEmail(string $value)
 * @method string getAddedAt()
 * @method Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template setAddedAt(string $value)
 * @method string getModifiedAt()
 * @method Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template setModifiedAt(string $value)
 * @method string getOrigTemplateCode()
 * @method Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template setOrigTemplateCode(string $value)
 * @method string getOrigTemplateVariables()
 * @method Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template setOrigTemplateVariables(string $value)
 * @method Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template setQueue(Mage_Core_Model_Abstract $value)
 * @method Mage_Core_Model_Email_Queue getQueue()
 * @method int hasQueue()
 *
 * @category    Mage
 * @package     Mage_Core
 * @author      Magento Core Team <core@magentocommerce.com>
 */
class Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template extends Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template_Abstract
{
    /**
     * Configuration path for default email templates
     */
    const XML_PATH_TEMPLATE_EMAIL               = 'global/template/email';
    const XML_PATH_SENDING_SET_RETURN_PATH      = 'system/smtp/set_return_path';
    const XML_PATH_SENDING_RETURN_PATH_EMAIL    = 'system/smtp/return_path_email';

    protected $_templateFilter;
    protected $_preprocessFlag = false;
    protected $_mail;
    protected $_bccEmails = array();

    static protected $_defaultTemplates;

    /**
     * Initialize email template model
     *
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('core/email_template');
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve mail object instance
     *
     * @return Zend_Mail
     */
    public function getMail()
    {
        if (is_null($this->_mail)) {
            $this->_mail = new Zend_Mail('utf-8');
        }
        return $this->_mail;
    }

    /**
     * Declare template processing filter
     *
     * @param   Varien_Filter_Template $filter
     * @return  Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template
     */
    public function setTemplateFilter(Varien_Filter_Template $filter)
    {
        $this->_templateFilter = $filter;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get filter object for template processing logi
     *
     * @return Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template_Filter
     */
    public function getTemplateFilter()
    {
        if (empty($this->_templateFilter)) {
            $this->_templateFilter = Mage::getModel('core/email_template_filter');
            $this->_templateFilter->setUseAbsoluteLinks($this->getUseAbsoluteLinks())
                ->setStoreId($this->getDesignConfig()->getStore());
        }
        return $this->_templateFilter;
    }

    /**
     * Load template by code
     *
     * @param   string $templateCode
     * @return   Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template
     */
    public function loadByCode($templateCode)
    {
        $this->addData($this->getResource()->loadByCode($templateCode));
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Load default email template from locale translate
     *
     * @param string $templateId
     * @param string $locale
     */
    public function loadDefault($templateId, $locale=null)
    {
        $defaultTemplates = self::getDefaultTemplates();
        if (!isset($defaultTemplates[$templateId])) {
            return $this;
        }

        $data = &$defaultTemplates[$templateId];
        $this->setTemplateType($data['type']=='html' ? self::TYPE_HTML : self::TYPE_TEXT);

        $templateText = Mage::app()->getTranslator()->getTemplateFile(
            $data['file'], 'email', $locale
        );

        if (preg_match('/<!--@subject\s*(.*?)\s*@-->/u', $templateText, $matches)) {
            $this->setTemplateSubject($matches[1]);
            $templateText = str_replace($matches[0], '', $templateText);
        }

        if (preg_match('/<!--@vars\s*((?:.)*?)\s*@-->/us', $templateText, $matches)) {
            $this->setData('orig_template_variables', str_replace("\n", '', $matches[1]));
            $templateText = str_replace($matches[0], '', $templateText);
        }

        if (preg_match('/<!--@styles\s*(.*?)\s*@-->/s', $templateText, $matches)) {
           $this->setTemplateStyles($matches[1]);
           $templateText = str_replace($matches[0], '', $templateText);
        }

        /**
         * Remove comment lines
         */
        $templateText = preg_replace('#\{\*.*\*\}#suU', '', $templateText);

        $this->setTemplateText($templateText);
        $this->setId($templateId);

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Retrive default templates from config
     *
     * @return array
     */
    static public function getDefaultTemplates()
    {
        if(is_null(self::$_defaultTemplates)) {
            self::$_defaultTemplates = Mage::getConfig()->getNode(self::XML_PATH_TEMPLATE_EMAIL)->asArray();
        }

        return self::$_defaultTemplates;
    }

    /**
     * Retrive default templates as options array
     *
     * @return array
     */
    static public function getDefaultTemplatesAsOptionsArray()
    {
        $options = array(
            array('value'=>'', 'label'=> '')
        );

        $idLabel = array();
        foreach (self::getDefaultTemplates() as $templateId => $row) {
            if (isset($row['@']) && isset($row['@']['module'])) {
                $module = $row['@']['module'];
            } else {
                $module = 'adminhtml';
            }
            $idLabel[$templateId] = Mage::helper($module)->__($row['label']);
        }
        asort($idLabel);
        foreach ($idLabel as $templateId => $label) {
            $options[] = array('value' => $templateId, 'label' => $label);
        }

        return $options;
    }

    /**
     * Return template id
     * return int|null
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->getTemplateId();
    }

    /**
     * Set id of template
     * @param int $value
     */
    public function setId($value)
    {
        return $this->setTemplateId($value);
    }

    /**
     * Return true if this template can be used for sending queue as main template
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function isValidForSend()
    {
        return !Mage::getStoreConfigFlag('system/smtp/disable')
            && $this->getSenderName()
            && $this->getSenderEmail()
            && $this->getTemplateSubject();
    }

    /**
     * Getter for template type
     *
     * @return int|string
     */
    public function getType(){
        return $this->getTemplateType();
    }

    /**
     * Process email template code
     *
     * @param   array $variables
     * @return  string
     */
    public function getProcessedTemplate(array $variables = array())
    {
        $processor = $this->getTemplateFilter();
        $processor->setUseSessionInUrl(false)
            ->setPlainTemplateMode($this->isPlain());

        if (!$this->_preprocessFlag) {
            $variables['this'] = $this;
        }

        if (isset($variables['subscriber']) && ($variables['subscriber'] instanceof Mage_Newsletter_Model_Subscriber)) {
            $processor->setStoreId($variables['subscriber']->getStoreId());
        }

        // Apply design config so that all subsequent code will run within the context of the correct store
        $this->_applyDesignConfig();

        // Populate the variables array with store, store info, logo, etc. variables
        $variables = $this->_addEmailVariables($variables, $processor->getStoreId());

        $processor
            ->setTemplateProcessor(array($this, 'getTemplateByConfigPath'))
            ->setIncludeProcessor(array($this, 'getInclude'))
            ->setVariables($variables);

        try {
            // Filter the template text so that all HTML content will be present
            $result = $processor->filter($this->getTemplateText());
            // If the {{inlinecss file=""}} directive was included in the template, grab filename to use for inlining
            $this->setInlineCssFile($processor->getInlineCssFile());
            // Now that all HTML has been assembled, run email through CSS inlining process
            $processedResult = $this->getPreparedTemplateText($result);
        }
        catch (Exception $e)   {
            $this->_cancelDesignConfig();
            throw $e;
        }
        $this->_cancelDesignConfig();
        return $processedResult;
    }

    /**
     * Makes additional text preparations for HTML templates
     *
     * @return string
     */
    /**
     * @param null $html
     * @return null|string
     */
    public function getPreparedTemplateText($html = null)
    {

        if ($this->isPlain() && $html) {
            return $html;
        } elseif ($this->isPlain()) {
            return $this->getTemplateText();
        }

        return $this->_applyInlineCss($html);
    }

    /**
     * Get template code for include directive
     *
     * @param   string $template
     * @param   array $variables
     * @return  string
     */
    public function getInclude($template, array $variables)
    {
        $thisClass = __CLASS__;
        $includeTemplate = new $thisClass();

        $includeTemplate->loadByCode($template);

        return $includeTemplate->getProcessedTemplate($variables);
    }

    /**
     * Send mail to recipient
     *
     * @param   array|string       $email        E-mail(s)
     * @param   array|string|null  $name         receiver name(s)
     * @param   array              $variables    template variables
     * @return  boolean
     **/
    public function send($email, $name = null, array $variables = array())
    {
        if (!$this->isValidForSend()) {
            Mage::logException(new Exception('This letter cannot be sent.')); // translation is intentionally omitted
            return false;
        }

        $emails = array_values((array)$email);
        $names = is_array($name) ? $name : (array)$name;
        $names = array_values($names);
        foreach ($emails as $key => $email) {
            if (!isset($names[$key])) {
                $names[$key] = substr($email, 0, strpos($email, '@'));
            }
        }

        $variables['email'] = reset($emails);
        $variables['name'] = reset($names);

        $this->setUseAbsoluteLinks(true);
        $text = $this->getProcessedTemplate($variables, true);
        $subject = $this->getProcessedTemplateSubject($variables);

        $setReturnPath = Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_SENDING_SET_RETURN_PATH);
        switch ($setReturnPath) {
            case 1:
                $returnPathEmail = $this->getSenderEmail();
                break;
            case 2:
                $returnPathEmail = Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_SENDING_RETURN_PATH_EMAIL);
                break;
            default:
                $returnPathEmail = null;
                break;
        }

        if ($this->hasQueue() && $this->getQueue() instanceof Mage_Core_Model_Email_Queue) {
            /** @var $emailQueue Mage_Core_Model_Email_Queue */
            $emailQueue = $this->getQueue();
            $emailQueue->setMessageBody($text);
            $emailQueue->setMessageParameters(array(
                    'subject'           => $subject,
                    'return_path_email' => $returnPathEmail,
                    'is_plain'          => $this->isPlain(),
                    'from_email'        => $this->getSenderEmail(),
                    'from_name'         => $this->getSenderName(),
                    'reply_to'          => $this->getMail()->getReplyTo(),
                    'return_to'         => $this->getMail()->getReturnPath(),
                ))
                ->addRecipients($emails, $names, Mage_Core_Model_Email_Queue::EMAIL_TYPE_TO)
                ->addRecipients($this->_bccEmails, array(), Mage_Core_Model_Email_Queue::EMAIL_TYPE_BCC);
            $emailQueue->addMessageToQueue();

            return true;
        }

        ini_set('SMTP', Mage::getStoreConfig('system/smtp/host'));
        ini_set('smtp_port', Mage::getStoreConfig('system/smtp/port'));

        $mail = $this->getMail();

        if ($returnPathEmail !== null) {
            $mailTransport = new Zend_Mail_Transport_Sendmail("-f".$returnPathEmail);
            Zend_Mail::setDefaultTransport($mailTransport);
        }

        foreach ($emails as $key => $email) {
            $mail->addTo($email, '=?utf-8?B?' . base64_encode($names[$key]) . '?=');
        }

        if ($this->isPlain()) {
            $mail->setBodyText($text);
        } else {
            $mail->setBodyHTML($text);
        }

        $mail->setSubject('=?utf-8?B?' . base64_encode($subject) . '?=');
        $mail->setFrom($this->getSenderEmail(), $this->getSenderName());

        try {
            $mail->send();
            $this->_mail = null;
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            $this->_mail = null;
            Mage::logException($e);
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Send transactional email to recipient
     *
     * @param   int $templateId
     * @param   string|array $sender sender information, can be declared as part of config path
     * @param   string $email recipient email
     * @param   string $name recipient name
     * @param   array $vars variables which can be used in template
     * @param   int|null $storeId
     *
     * @throws Mage_Core_Exception
     *
     * @return  Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template
     */
    public function sendTransactional($templateId, $sender, $email, $name, $vars=array(), $storeId=null)
    {
        $this->setSentSuccess(false);
        if (($storeId === null) && $this->getDesignConfig()->getStore()) {
            $storeId = $this->getDesignConfig()->getStore();
        }

        if (is_numeric($templateId)) {
            $queue = $this->getQueue();
            $this->load($templateId);
            $this->setQueue($queue);
        } else {
            $localeCode = Mage::getStoreConfig('general/locale/code', $storeId);
            $this->loadDefault($templateId, $localeCode);
        }

        if (!$this->getId()) {
            throw Mage::exception('Mage_Core', Mage::helper('core')->__('Invalid transactional email code: %s', $templateId));
        }

        if (!is_array($sender)) {
            $this->setSenderName(Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_' . $sender . '/name', $storeId));
            $this->setSenderEmail(Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_' . $sender . '/email', $storeId));
        } else {
            $this->setSenderName($sender['name']);
            $this->setSenderEmail($sender['email']);
        }

        if (!isset($vars['store'])) {
            $vars['store'] = Mage::app()->getStore($storeId);
        }
        $this->setSentSuccess($this->send($email, $name, $vars));
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Process email subject
     *
     * @param   array $variables
     * @return  string
     */
    public function getProcessedTemplateSubject(array $variables)
    {
        $processor = $this->getTemplateFilter();

        if(!$this->_preprocessFlag) {
            $variables['this'] = $this;
        }

        $processor->setVariables($variables);

        $this->_applyDesignConfig();
        try{
            $processedResult = $processor->filter($this->getTemplateSubject());
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            $this->_cancelDesignConfig();
            throw $e;
        }
        $this->_cancelDesignConfig();
        return $processedResult;
    }

    public function addBcc($bcc)
    {
        if (is_array($bcc)) {
            foreach ($bcc as $email) {
                $this->_bccEmails[] = $email;
                $this->getMail()->addBcc($email);
            }
        }
        elseif ($bcc) {
            $this->_bccEmails[] = $bcc;
            $this->getMail()->addBcc($bcc);
        }
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Set Return Path
     *
     * @param string $email
     * @return Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template
     */
    public  function setReturnPath($email)
    {
        $this->getMail()->setReturnPath($email);
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Add Reply-To header
     *
     * @param string $email
     * @return Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template
     */
    public function setReplyTo($email)
    {
        $this->getMail()->setReplyTo($email);
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Parse variables string into array of variables
     *
     * @param string $variablesString
     * @return array
     */
    protected function _parseVariablesString($variablesString)
    {
        $variables = array();
        if ($variablesString && is_string($variablesString)) {
            $variablesString = str_replace("\n", '', $variablesString);
            $variables = Zend_Json::decode($variablesString);
        }
        return $variables;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve option array of variables
     *
     * @param boolean $withGroup if true wrap variable options in group
     * @return array
     */
    public function getVariablesOptionArray($withGroup = false)
    {
        $optionArray = array();
        $variables = $this->_parseVariablesString($this->getData('orig_template_variables'));
        if ($variables) {
            foreach ($variables as $value => $label) {
                $optionArray[] = array(
                    'value' => '{{' . $value . '}}',
                    'label' => Mage::helper('core')->__('%s', $label)
                );
            }
            if ($withGroup) {
                $optionArray = array(
                    'label' => Mage::helper('core')->__('Template Variables'),
                    'value' => $optionArray
                );
            }
        }
        return $optionArray;
    }

    /**
     * Validate email template code
     *
     * @return Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template
     */
    protected function _beforeSave()
    {
        $code = $this->getTemplateCode();
        if (empty($code)) {
            Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('core')->__('The template Name must not be empty.'));
        }
        if($this->_getResource()->checkCodeUsage($this)) {
            Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('core')->__('Duplicate Of Template Name'));
        }
        return parent::_beforeSave();
    }
}
```

cron log:

```
2016-06-13T12:05:07+00:00 DEBUG (7): Pending schedule for "aoescheduler_heartbeat" at "2016-06-13 12:10" already exists 1 times. Skipping.
2016-06-13T12:05:07+00:00 DEBUG (7): Pending schedule for "aoescheduler_heartbeat" at "2016-06-13 12:15" already exists 1 times. Skipping.
2016-06-13T12:05:07+00:00 DEBUG (7): Pending schedule for "captcha_delete_expired_images" at "2016-06-13 12:10" already exists 1 times. Skipping.
2016-06-13T12:05:07+00:00 DEBUG (7): Pending schedule for "core_email_queue_send_all" at "2016-06-13 12:06" already exists 1 times. Skipping.
2016-06-13T12:05:07+00:00 DEBUG (7): Pending schedule for "core_email_queue_send_all" at "2016-06-13 12:07" already exists 1 times. Skipping.
2016-06-13T12:05:07+00:00 DEBUG (7): Pending schedule for "core_email_queue_send_all" at "2016-06-13 12:08" already exists 1 times. Skipping.
2016-06-13T12:05:07+00:00 DEBUG (7): Pending schedule for "core_email_queue_send_all" at "2016-06-13 12:09" already exists 1 times. Skipping.
2016-06-13T12:05:07+00:00 DEBUG (7): Pending schedule for "core_email_queue_send_all" at "2016-06-13 12:10" already exists 1 times. Skipping.
2016-06-13T12:05:07+00:00 DEBUG (7): Pending schedule for "core_email_queue_send_all" at "2016-06-13 12:11" already exists 1 times. Skipping.
2016-06-13T12:05:07+00:00 DEBUG (7): Pending schedule for "core_email_queue_send_all" at "2016-06-13 12:12" already exists 1 times. Skipping.
2016-06-13T12:05:07+00:00 DEBUG (7): Pending schedule for "core_email_queue_send_all" at "2016-06-13 12:13" already exists 1 times. Skipping.
2016-06-13T12:05:07+00:00 DEBUG (7): Pending schedule for "core_email_queue_send_all" at "2016-06-13 12:14" already exists 1 times. Skipping.
2016-06-13T12:05:07+00:00 DEBUG (7): Pending schedule for "core_email_queue_send_all" at "2016-06-13 12:15" already exists 1 times. Skipping.
2016-06-13T12:05:07+00:00 DEBUG (7): Pending schedule for "core_email_queue_send_all" at "2016-06-13 12:16" already exists 1 times. Skipping.
2016-06-13T12:05:07+00:00 DEBUG (7): Pending schedule for "core_email_queue_send_all" at "2016-06-13 12:17" already exists 1 times. Skipping.
2016-06-13T12:05:07+00:00 DEBUG (7): Pending schedule for "core_email_queue_send_all" at "2016-06-13 12:18" already exists 1 times. Skipping.
2016-06-13T12:05:07+00:00 DEBUG (7): Pending schedule for "core_email_queue_send_all" at "2016-06-13 12:19" already exists 1 times. Skipping.
```

system log:

```
2016-01-29T18:00:27+00:00 DEBUG (7): SQLSTATE[HY000] [1040] Too many connections
2016-01-29T18:00:50+00:00 DEBUG (7): SQLSTATE[HY000] [1040] Too many connections
2016-02-18T20:25:02+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: PDO::__construct(): MySQL server has gone away  in /home/username/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php on line 129
2016-02-18T20:25:02+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: PDO::__construct(): Error while reading greeting packet. PID=22  in /home/username/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php on line 129
2016-03-24T07:10:40+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): MySQL server has gone away  in /home/username/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php on line 228
2016-03-24T07:10:40+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): Error reading result set's header  in /home/username/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php on line 228
2016-03-24T07:10:40+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): MySQL server has gone away  in /home/username/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php on line 228
2016-03-24T07:10:40+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): Error reading result set's header  in /home/username/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php on line 228
2016-03-31T03:13:08+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): MySQL server has gone away  in /home/username/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php on line 228
2016-03-31T03:13:08+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): Error reading result set's header  in /home/username/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php on line 228
2016-03-31T03:13:08+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): MySQL server has gone away  in /home/username/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php on line 228
2016-03-31T03:13:08+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): Error reading result set's header  in /home/username/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php on line 228
2016-04-01T11:11:21+00:00 DEBUG (7): SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory
```

Theres a load of errors in system.log for a store locator im using, but can't imagine that is linked to this issue.

Comment: Queue does have a couple of records in now. but they're not sending out.

Comment: Do you have anything in system.log ?

Comment: Was this working before? When did you notice the problem?

Comment: is mail server is installed from server side ? also can you try smtp extension.

Comment: so it works fine without the SMTP extension?

Comment: @SML no doesnt work at all

Comment: any error msg in your AOE scheduler?

Comment: check if you have another instance of the same task running without proper termination.

Comment: okay upon re-reading the info, did you stop getting entries in the cron_mail_queue table after a version update? are all the patches up to date? another possibility is extension conflict

Comment: @SML I dont believe it to be a conflict as we have 3 sites on the server all with the same problem, using different extensions, one without hardly any extensions. Theres some records in the table now, just not sending out. We got hacked a while ago and tons of spam was sent out. this has now been stopped and ive been advised email clients may have blacklisted us, but im not convinced that is the issue.

Comment: any error msg in your AOE scheduler?

Comment: @sml i dont believe so, all seem to be running with green lights. Is there a report somewhere? If there is I cant find it?

Comment: if we were to rule out that the system fail to write entries into the cron_mail_queue table due to some wrongful implementation of update. then the queue is getting clean up but no actual email is sent. My guess is 1) an instance of the same task not being proper terminated, causing all later instance of the same task not being executed. To solve this, you need to delete all instances of that task.

Comment: 2) your email server might be dropping emails originated from cron, you can write a script to test this but given you couldn't get it to work with a SMTP extension either then this is less likely.  3) you can do a test run of "forgotten password" request for an account registered with an email address under the same domain, if that goes through then being blacklisted by other servers is a possibility.

Comment: 4) disable all of your extension and re-enable one by one to look for the culprit, if any 5) test to ensure that entry does get write to cron_mail_queue in the first place

Comment: @SML I've teste the password with the same domain suffix and it still didnt send.

Comment: Do the debugging steps I suggested in the following sequence 5), 1), 2), 4). Let me know how it goes and best of luck =)

Comment: Any answer or solution for the question, I am facing the same issue recently